# How to create advanced fileters?

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, filter

My users want to see how many items are created in 2016 in a list, but in the default filter they can add filter only day by day. Is there a way to make possible to add start and end date for the filter of creation date?

Their scound wish is to show somewhere how many element are listed after they activated a filter.

I know they can do this if they export the list to exel, but I would like to make it possible in the browser.

Thanks you very much for any advices or examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a view, call it 2016, using filter dates of >= 1/1/16 and <=12/31/16 for the date range.  Then in the  view settings go to the Totals section, find a column that displays in your view, and toggle the Total field to "Count".

[More general info here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-lists-0A1C3ACE-DEF0-44AF-B225-CFA8D92C52D7).